# SessionHandlerInterface not found

Tags: php, session, interface

I have this error:

> Interface 'SessionHandlerInterface' not found in
>   /membri/francescorizzi/php_SessionMgr/MySessionHandler.php on line 3

here is my interface code (taken from php.net as a start point):

```
<?php
class MySessionHandler implements SessionHandlerInterface{

private $savePath;

public function open($savePath, $sessionName)
{
    $this->savePath = $savePath;
    if (!is_dir($this->savePath)) {
        mkdir($this->savePath, 0777);
    }

    return true;
}

public function close()
{
    return true;
}

public function read($id)
{
    return (string)@file_get_contents("$this->savePath/sess_$id");
}

public function write($id, $data)
{
    return file_put_contents("$this->savePath/sess_$id", $data) === false ? false : true;
}

public function destroy($id)
{
    $file = "$this->savePath/sess_$id";
    if (file_exists($file)) {
        unlink($file);
    }

    return true;
}

public function gc($maxlifetime)
{
    foreach (glob("$this->savePath/sess_*") as $file) {
        if (filemtime($file) + $maxlifetime < time() && file_exists($file)) {
            unlink($file);
        }
    }

    return true;
}
}
```

I tried also using `implements \SessionHandlerInterface` or `use SessionHandlerInterface` but this didn't work.

How to solve this?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

I noticed that if i load all my code throught URL:

> www.site.org/main.php?...

it works, but if i use this:

> www.site.org/index.html?...

the error comes up.

My index.html page includes the main.php code.
Where is the error?

**INDEX.HTML CODE:**

```
<html>
<body bgcolor="#000000">
<body text="grey">
<?php include('Main.php') ?>
</body>
</html>
```

**.htaccess file:**

```
# # av:php5-engine
AddHandler av-php56 .php
AddType application/x-httpd-php .htm .html
RewriteRule ^index.html$ main.php
```

Answer (score -1):

Is it possible that you are using an older PHP version? As stated in the official PHP documentation, the SessionHandlerInterface is only available starting with PHP 5.4.0

Comment: MAYBE I SOLVED IT.

I'm new to php and i wanted to load my php page through "index.html"

if i put in my url: "www.site.org/main.php?..." it works.

if i put in my url: "www.site.org/index.html?..." it shows the error...

Index.html includes "main.php" where all my php code starts.

Can you tell me where is the difference?

Comment: It is a bit confusing that you seem to be getting a PHP error. I'll explain why. I assume you're using Apache. Normally (when I say normally, I mean using the default configuration) you server should not interpret the PHP code inside files with the extension `.html`. Now, I understand that there might be situations where you might want the browser to display index.html instead of main.php. If that's the case, you can simply create a `.htaccess` file with the following content `RewriteRule ^index.html$ main.php [QSA,L]`. This will tell Apache that index.html is actually main.php.

Comment: Also, you only need a single file called main.php, you don't need to have an actual index.html file for this to work. Hope that helps. Let me know if I should explain it in more detail.

Comment: i edited my post in order to let you understand better my situation, i tried using html.it webpage and including again main.php but the error came up again.

Maybe i'm setting wrong something.

PLEASE NOTE: i am pretty new to php and i'm testing everything on a webservice which offers me the possibility to upload my site and my code. No apache knowledge and no other toole are used more than eclipse (php) and ftp access for testing.

www.francescorizzi.altervista.org/index.html
www.francescorizzi.altervista.org/main.php